# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'category_id' cannot be null")?

Tags: python, django

goods.py

```
class Goods(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(GoodsCategory, verbose_name='xxx')
    goods_sn = models.CharField(default='', max_length=50, verbose_name='xxx')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name='xxx')
    click_num = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='xxx')
    sold_num = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='xxx')
```

import_goods_data.py

```
from apps.goods.models import Goods, GoodsCategory, GoodsImage

from db_tools.data.product_data import row_data

for goods_detail in row_data:
    goods = Goods()
    goods.name = goods_detail['name']
    goods.market_price = float(int(goods_detail['market_price'].replace('￥', '').replace('&', '')))
    goods.shop_price = float(int(goods_detail['sale_price'].replace('&', '').replace('元', '')))
    goods.goods_brief = goods_detail['desc'] if goods_detail['desc'] is not None else ''
    goods_goods_desc = goods_detail['goods_desc'] if goods_detail['goods_desc'] is not None else ''
    goods.goods_front_image = goods_detail['images'][0] if goods_detail['images'] is not None else ''

    category_name = goods_detail['categorys'][-1]
    category = GoodsCategory.objects.filter(name=category_name)
    if category:
        goods.category = category[0]
    goods.save()
```

in the goods.py, not 'category_id', why running 'import_goods_data.py' get the error:

```
_mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'category_id' cannot be null")
```

and must be add 'category_id'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `category` is a required field, but you are not setting `goods.category` if a category with that name does not exist.

How you handle this is up to you. Perhaps you want to create the category if it doesn't exist:

```
categories = GoodsCategory.objects.filter(name=category_name)
if categories.exist():
    category = categories[0]
else:
    category = GoodsCategory.objects.create(name=category_name)
goods.category = category[0]
```

If the `name` field is unique, you could simplify the code by using [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create).

```
category, created = GoodsCategory.objects.get_or_create(name=category_name)
goods.category = category
```

Comment: I also encountered this problem, although I solved it according to this answer, but it was invalid.I did the same project with you.

Comment: Can you give me a hand?

Comment: @kerberos that’s not enough information to solve your problem. Please ask a new question.